# Filter on Field in Data Source before Syncing

Tags: marketing-cloud, data-synchronization

I want to Sync my `Account` Object with marketing cloud but before syncing I would like filter on some fields and only the records which have a value  in the field used in filter.

Or can I only filter by `Date` as mentioned in help document ?

Answer (score -1):

@Roberto
You can use sharing setting and add filter criteria to the same.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/73180)

Comment: @Reshma It was by mistake that i clicked on delete link. I didn't mean to do so.

Comment: Can you add a little detail on how this works?